# Deploy a Java app to GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp

I tried to deploy a pushbot on GAE by using: http://code.google.com/p/partychapp/source/browse/pushbot source code.

I can see the bot online, but it never answer my command, did I miss something?

The error like:

> 0.1.0.10 - - [20/Dec/2011:03:53:40 -0800] "POST /_ah/xmpp/message/chat/ HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - - "mypushbot.appspot.com"
>   ms=1472 cpu_ms=937 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.026155 loading_request=1
>   instance=00c61b117c16beda068d441a41e0403d7f2a W 2011-12-20
>   03:53:40.600 EXCEPTION  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   info.persistent.pushbot.PushSubscriberServlet     at
>   com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-dee70bec3ae50151(Request.java)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)    at
>   org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you compiled the project and ran it locally before pushing it to the cloud?

Comment: Opps... No, I just did 'appcfg.sh update war/', I don't know much Java, how can I compile it by linux command without using a huge SDK?

Comment: Ok you need to compile it to fill you war folder with the .class files. I only work with the google plugin for eclipse and i don't think it's possible to compile without the 'huge' SDK.

Comment: Thanks, Shagaan. I installed the eclipse and google plugin.. Then how do I compile the java files?

Comment: Once you imported the project in your workspace, just run the project as a google web application. It will compile it and deploye it on your localhost:8888.
If it works, you can push the war folder of the eclipse project to the cloud.

Comment: I even don't know how to import the pushbot source to eclipse, sorry for the Java n00b...

Comment: :D
File/Import/Existing Project into Workspace

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [JRE Class White List](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html) for GAE, before deploying it to GAE?

You can also find relevant discussion related to this (probably), on this site: [JRE Class Black List For GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752399/google-app-engine-jre-class-black-list)

Comment: Hi, A pushbot already running on GAE at: http://push-bot.appspot.com/, I think the code is OK for GAE :)

Comment: Which XMPP libraries are you using? As per GAE rules, you cannot open a socket. You can anyways use the XMPP libraries supplied by GAE: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124416/can-gae-act-as-an-xmpp-server]